# Setting the source of an image in android to be a URL

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to do something in the lines of this:

```
imageView.setSource("my-url");
```

I know there is no function called setSource but is there no other possibility other than having to download it from an url?

I mean I could probably do something like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.wallng.com/images/2013/08/image-explosion-colors-background-beautiful-263613.jpg");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

            InputStream is = buf.getContent();


            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");
            }



            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(source,total.toString());
```

But my question is :

Instead of doing the above code ( using a DefaultHttpClient ) is there a simpler way to set the source of an image?

And even if I do the code above how do I go around and set the source of an ImageView?
What would be the function that I could use to set the source of the variable

```
imageView
```

to be my source which is:

```
http://www.wallng.com/images/2013/08/image-explosion-colors-background-beautiful-263613.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472175/3006350

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;
InputStream in = null;
BufferedOutputStream out = null;

try {
    in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

    final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
    copy(in, out);
    out.flush();

    final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //options.inSampleSize = 1;

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
} finally {
    closeStream(in);
    closeStream(out);
}

return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using some image loader library like Universal Image Loader, Volly's Image loader etc